# Element not Clickable ( Chrome + Selenium + Python)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Chromewebdriver /Selenium in Python
I tried several solutions ( actions, maximize window etc) to get rid of this exception without success.
The error is :
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (410, 513). Other element would receive the click: ...

The code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url = 'https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/welcome#/tmview/detail/EM500000018203824'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "D:\Python\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(30)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Show more').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code on my linux pc with latest libraries, python3 and chromedriver. It works perfectly(to my mind). So try to update everything and try again(Try to not to leave chrome). Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url = 'https://www.tmdn.org/tmview/welcome#/tmview/detail/EM500000018203824'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(30)
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Show more').click()
```

P.S. chromedriver is in the same folder as script.

Answer (score 0):

code is working fine but if you manually click on some other element after   page loaded before sleep time is over then you can recreate same error

for example after site is loaded and i clicked on element **search for trade mark with similar image** then selenium is not able to find search element.so maybe some other part of your code is clicking on  other element and loading different url due to which 
selenium is generating this error .your code is fine just check for conflict cases.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance.
Actually, the issue was the panel on the footer of the web page 'We use cookies....' which is overlapping with the 'Show more' link, when the driver tries to click, the click was intercepted by that panel.

The solution is to close that panel, and the code worked fine.